# How to scroll up/down in the VM console of Ubuntu 20.04 server?

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys

with previous major versions of Ubuntu(e.g. 16.04), I was able to scroll up/down the output with `Shift+PageUp` or `Shift+PageDown`. However, ever since Ubuntu 20.04 (maybe 18.04.03, according to [How to scroll in Ubuntu Server 18.04.3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1209880/how-to-scroll-in-ubuntu-server-18-04-3)), nothing happens with those key presses.

Please note that this is Ubuntu server, without X applications.

I tried with Control or Fn too.

I tried it on both VMware Workstation and VirtualBox.

(I'm aware that I can use less, screen or ssh to work-around the problem, but it's weird that the native way is suddenly broken.)

Answer (score 2):

Console "Soft scroll" has been removed from them mainline kernel, and I believe the change was backported to the kernel supplied with 20LTS.
I'm disappointed, as well.  It's an incredibly useful feature, particularly if there are a bunch of kernel messages that relate to the possible causes of a recent lock-up or lock-out condition.
One day, I hope to see a "dmesg and systemd journal viewer" that resides on its own TTY, kinda like how ESXi and FreeBSD do it, which lets you scroll and filter messages.

Answer (score 0):

Scrolling with less works until inputs are required by the program.

```bash
(some commands) | less
```

Perhaps some i/o redirections can still achieve the result.
Observe this:

```bash
(
for (( i=0; i<100; i++ )); do
    echo "ok $i"
done;
sleep 10
read a 1>&2
echo $a 1>&2
) | less
```

Comments please.